# Notation in Hartshorne book about monoidal transformations (blow-ups of surfaces along points)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, notation

I'm starting the process of learning the concept of blow-up for surfaces along a point.

At page 386 of Hartshorne's book, the author defines the monoidal transformation of a surface $X$. But at the beginning of the chapter I find the following sentence:

> Throughtout this chapter a *surface* will mean a **non-singular** projective surface over an algebraically closed field.

Now, if the "aim" of the blow-up is the resolution of singularities, what is the sense of defining it for non-singular surfaces?

**edit:** Why for example in Beauville's book there is no mention to the non-singularity?

Comment: Usually, it is a singular curve (on a non-singular surface) which you blow up.

Comment: Addition to my previous comment : you can look at Proposition 3.8 on page 390.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say

> if the "aim" of the blow-up is the resolution of singularities, what is the sense of defining it for non-singular surfaces?

But that is a false premise. Blow-ups arise unavoidably in solving all kinds of problems in algebraic geometry, even when you start from a nonsingular variety. The basic reason is that *rational maps can be resolved by blowups*.

As an example of how this arises in practice, look no further than the exact page of Hartshorne you mention (p. 386): he says there

> We will see later (5.5) that any birational transformation of surfaces can be factored into monoidal transformations and their inverses.